# EF Core - Delete Migration Folder, but keep database?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I had some problems with migrating and updating my database, so I deleted my whole `Migrations` folder.

I would now like to update the database without deleting the data.

The problem is that when I now make a new migration, it will have all the already existing tables/classes in it with a `Create` statement. When I try to update the database, then I get an error that the table already exists (ORA-00955).

I have found: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/managing?tabs=dotnet-core-cli
, however when I create the script it still only has a `CREATE` instead of an `CREATE IF NOT EXISTS`, so this does not solve my problem.

How can I keep working on my database, with my current data, while still being able to update it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple approaches to this. For example with your current one - after adding new initial migration - manually add it's id (check the value passed to the [`MigrationAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationattribute?view=efcore-7.0) in the `{MigrationName}.Designer.cs` file, usually it matches the migration name) to the `__EFMigrationsHistory` table in all the databases which you want to keep (optionally you can delete all the records from it before inserting a new migration name).

Read more:

- [Resetting all migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/managing?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#resetting-all-migrations) (actually this  approach is described here)
- [Custom Migrations History Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/history-table)

Comment: Thanks! I somehow did overlook the Comment on the site.
But something else: How can I then update changed Properties? ie: I have in my Model new Properties, , but not yet in the Database. However, when I create the Migration those Properties are there and in future Migrations not added anymore.

Comment: @SuperNev That is not a very good situation. One way to handle it - add empty migration after newly created one and then manually update Up method so it checks if properties are present and if not - creates them. Or postpone the migration "merge" until all databases are updated to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

This is now documented:

> It's also possible to reset all migrations and create a single one
> without losing your data. This is sometimes called "squashing", and
> involves some manual work:
>
> - Delete your Migrations folder
> - Create a new migration and generate a SQL script for it
> - In your database, delete all rows from the migrations history table
> - Insert a single row into the migrations history, to record that the first migration has already been applied, since your tables are
>   already there. The insert SQL is the last operation in the SQL script
>   generated above.

[Managing Migrations - EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/managing?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)