# Moving EF Core Models and Migrations to a new Solution

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I've been working on ASP.NET Web API project that was using EF Core Code-First Approach.

Now functionality of this API is being merged with another API, so I need to move that code to a new solution. New API will be using the same database created with Code-First Approach. Additionally, new solution uses a different architecture approach, so the models are separated into different projects, and original DbContext is broken down into multiple different DbContexts each providing access to a smaller subset of models.

I want to move my Migrations to a new solution, but not sure how to do that properly. Other questions on StackOverflow deal with a simpler case of moving Migrations to a new assembly without changing the assemblies of the models

Comment: Do you have an option to simply delete the migrations and recreate a new init?

Comment: I would suggest to delete the migrations and create a new `Initial` one (or several once per context) and then insert corresponding record(s) in migration table for existing databases. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75696237/2501279)